# Sort the unsorted text file and rewrite to same text file in sorted order

Tags: php

I have a question.  I am in process of learning how to read/write files, but having little trouble trying to do both at the same time in same php script.  I have a text file with words like this,

```
Richmond,Virginia
Seattle,Washington
Los Angeles,California
Dallas,Texas
Jacksonville,Florida
```

I wrote a code to sort them in order and this will display in sort order by City.

```
<?php
$file = file("states.txt");
sort($file);
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
{
  $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
  echo $states[0], $states[1],"<br />";
}
?>
```

From this, how can I rewrite those sorted information back into the states.txt file?

Comment: *(reference)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to write the contents of `$file` back to the file would be using [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) in collaboration with [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
file_put_contents("states.txt", implode($file));
```

Comment: Sebastian, that was just perfect.  All I had to change in that was to remove "\n" because it was adding extra blank line between each records.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fopen and fwrite.

```
$fileWrite = fopen("filePah", "w");

for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
{
    fWrite($fileWrite, $file[i]);
}
fClose($fileWrite);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file = file("states.txt");
sort($file);
$newContent = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
{
  $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
  $newContent .= $states[0] .', '. $states[1] . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('states.txt',$newContent);
?>
```

[PHP: file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: I've seend that function.  I'll try that too.  Thanks. :D

Comment: I also removed the "<br />" because in the .txt file you should use PHP_EOL ("\n" or "\r\n").

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$fo = fopen("filename", "w");
$content = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++) {
    $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
    $content .= $states[0] . "," . $states[1] . "\n";
}
fwrite($fo, $content);
fclose($fo);
```

Comment: But where's the sorting part..or do i just add that code followed by my code?

Comment: you just add your part before mine and it should work allright

Answer (score 1):

this is a little extended, however I thought it might be useful to smb. I have an m3u playlist and need only particular rows filtered, sorted and printed. Credits go to Devil:

```
<?php

//specify that the variable is of type array
$masiv = array();

//read the file
$file = '/home/zlobi/radio/pls/all.m3u';  

$f = fopen($file, "r");

while ($line = fgets($f))
{
//skip rows with #EXT
if(strpos($line, "#EXT") !== false) continue;

$text = str_replace('.ogg', ' ', $line);  
$text = str_replace('/home/zlobi/radio/',' ',$text);

//add the song as an element in an array
$masiv[] = $text;
}
$f = fclose($f);

//sort the array
sort($masiv);

//pass via the array, take each element and print it
foreach($masiv as $pesen)

print $pesen.'<br/>';

?>
```

masiv is array, pesen is song in Bulgarian :)
CAPital letters are sorted first.

Regads

Answer (score 0):

Once you are done reading the file into the array by a call to [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). You can open the file for writing by using the [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function, write into the file using the [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and close the file handle using [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php):

```
<?php
$file = file("states.txt");                  // read file into array.
$fh = fopen('states.txt','w') or die("..."); // open same file for writing.
sort($file);
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
{
    $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
    echo $states[0], $states[1],"<br />";
    fwrite($fh,"$states[0],$states[1] <br />"); // write to file.
}
fclose($fh); // close file.
?>
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not on my computer, so I can't test it now, but I will later.  Also, if I want to do this in descending order, I'm assuming that I can just change sort($file); to rsort($file); and that should work?

Comment: Yes, you need to use rsort($file) to sort the file contents in reverse order.

Comment: If I did, my bad...but I don't think I did that.  Anyhow it seems I need to fix from your example to get rid of "<br />" and insert "/n" since we're writing into a text file.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...I just clicked to vote up, but I need more reputation to do that. :(

Comment: @unicornaddict - Change your answer and I'll give you an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, write to it, close it (this assumes $file is the variable from your code):

```
$fp = fopen('states.txt', 'w');
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
    fwrite($fp, $file[$i]);
}
fclose($fp);
```

And see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: I've checked php.net, but they didn't show how to sort and write back into the same file.  I've learned how to write to file, but I wasn't sure how to do both at the same time in one php script.

Comment: ummm ... open file for reading, read file, close file (you did all in one step with `file()`), sort, open file for writing, write to file, close file (the last three steps could be done via `file_put_contents()`, as Sebastian P. pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

This is by far the fastest and most elegant solution that I have found, when I had the same problem.
If you're on Linux (with exec allowed in PHP configuration) you can do the following (provided you want to sort files numerically):

```
exec("sort -n " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
```

Basically, execute bash command **sort** that sorts the lines in a file numerically.
If you want to keep the data in the original file do this:

```
exec("sort -n " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
exec("rm " . $pathToOriginalFile);
exec("mv " . $pathToSortedFile . " " . $pathToOriginalFile);
```

If you want an alphabetical sort just exclude -n (--numeric-sort) option.

```
exec("sort " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
```

For me the command took about 3 seconds to sort 10 million lines in the file on the server.

You can find more about sort here http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usort.htm

Hope it helps.