# How to sort a text file by the second index in each line using php

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, text

Hey guys I currently have a text file that looks like this

Los Angeles, California
Seattle, Washington
Detroit, Michigan

The city and state is separated by a comma. I know how to sort the text file by the city, but I don't know how to sort the text file by the state.

Any Suggestion?

I tried this

```
<?php 
    $file = file("states.txt"); 
    sort($file); 
    for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++) { 
        $states = explode(",", $file[$i]); 
        echo $states[0], $states[1],"<br />"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, otherwise this just looks like a ___do it for me___ request

Comment: I did something like this.<?php
$file = file("states.txt");
sort($file);
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
{
  $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
  echo $states[0], $states[1],"<br />";
}
?>

Comment: You can edit you r question any time to add information. Its better than trying to read code in a comment

Comment: I did something like this. I got this from another stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630380/sort-the-unsorted-text-file-and-rewrite-to-same-text-file-in-sorted-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your text file is called `cities.txt`.
Here is simple solution using `file`, `usort`, `strpos` and `strcmp` functions:

```
$cities = file("cities.txt");   // reading file contents as array of strings(lines)

usort($cities, function($a, $b){  // sorting by the first character of the state name
    return strcmp($a[(strpos($a, ",") + 2)], $b[(strpos($b, ",") + 2)]);
});

//file_put_contents("cities.txt", implode("", $cities));  // for saving sorted file contents

print_r($cities);
```

The output(as array):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Los Angeles, California

    [1] => Detroit, Michigan

    [2] => Seattle, Washington

)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @NFSNFS, you're welcome

Comment: By the way is there any other way I can do this same task. Something more in the line like function($file, $index).  The file variable would be something like $file = file("text.txt") and $index would be like which column of data we want to sort the file by?

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If there was another column after the state like the zip code would I make a variable $c and  repeat the same structure like you did for $a and $b?

Comment: show the exemplary string with zip code